# Probabilities for 2-grams are higher than 1-grams in arpa file produced by kenlm

Tags: nlp, corpora, frequency, machine-translation, n-grams

I'm using the 1 billion word language corpus to build a model with 1 and 2-grams.  When using the [lmplz](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/estimation/) program that comes with kenlm, I noticed that the arpa file seems to have higher probabilities associated with 2-grams than derived 1-grams.  For example, the log probabilities of "sick" and "feel sick":

```
sick : -4.48
feel sick : -2.6995
```

Can anyone explain why this occurs?  I would have thought that the probability of a single word in a text would be higher than a pair of words in the same text?

For example in the following text, not including punctuation:

```
I feel happy, so very happy.  You make me very happy.
```

There are:

```
11 1-grams
9  2-grams
```

Giving probabilities:

```
"happy" 3/11 = 0.27
"very happy" 2/9 = 0.22
```

I find it hard to think of a situation where a 2-gram would be more probable than a 1-gram contained within the 2-gram.

Comment: There is a proposal (as at July 2014) for a Natural Language Processing stack exchange which would suit this type of question, please follow it!  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74384/natural-language-processing

Comment: the NLP stack-exchange didn't get enough traction.

Answer (score 1):

This could occur when the single word is much more commonly used in a set phrase or idiom than on its own.  For example, it is much more common to see the word 'eke' with an 'out' than it standing alone.

Comment: I have added an example to the question to show why I don't think this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat new to NLP, so if someone else has a more complete answer, please go ahead and clarify.

What I believe is going on here is that the 2-gram (and 3-gram etc.) probabilities are actually conditional probabilities, while the 1-gram probabilities are unconditional probabilities.

So in your example, the probability of `sick` is `10^-4.48` = 0.00003311, or a 1 in 30200 chance of occurring. On the other hand, the probability of `sick` *given that `feel` precedes it* is `10^-2.6995` = 0.00199, or a 1 in 500 chance.

In other words, `P(sick)` = `10^-4.48`, and `P(sick|feel)` = `10^-2.6995`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you have a link to anything that supports your argument?